# Getting pointer to point at address so that changes are reflected

Tags: c, pointers, buffer

I'm having such a hard time with pointers. Basically, I want a buff void pointer to point at an unsigned char kbdbuff[] so that whenever there are changes to kbdbuff[], it's reflected in the value pointed by buff.
The closest I got to was going about doing this:

```
kbdbuff[0] = 4;
unsigned char *tempbuf = buff;
*tempbuf = *kbdbuff;
```

Buff pointer pointed to 4 in the end, but the problem is that whatever changes are made after the pointer was assigned are not reflected in the value pointed by buff. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you declare `kbdbuff` and `buff` ?

Comment: Why a `void` pointer? You can't dereference a `void` pointer. You must know the type of data it's pointing to and typecast it to dereference it.

Comment: @Mouin buff was given as a parameter in the form of "void* buff" and the char array was "unsigned char kbdbuff[4]"

Comment: @FiddlingBits The function stub was given like this...

Comment: @alk you're right, I should've put "unsigned char *tempbuf". Still, I don't think this will fix it...

Comment: why the `tempbuff` ? if you use `buff = kdbuff; kdbuff[0] = 4;`then in `buff[0]` you will get 4

Comment: rather than adding bits and pieces of your code in the comments, edit your question and put them there.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this? (given the info you've provided):

```
int main(void)
{
    void* buff;
    unsigned int kbdbuff[4];

    buff = kbdbuff;

    kbdbuff[0] = 4;
    printf("kbdbuff[0] = %d\n", kbdbuff[0]);
    printf("buff[0] = %d\n", ((int*)buff)[0]);

    kbdbuff[0] = 3;
    printf("kbdbuff[0] = %d\n", kbdbuff[0]);
    printf("buff[0] = %d\n", ((int*)buff)[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
kbdbuff[0] = 4
buff[0] = 4
kbdbuff[0] = 3
buff[0] = 3
```